# How to get the currently running custom Threads variables

Tags: java, multithreading

Here is my custom thread class

```
  public class ThreadEngine extends Thread{
  private int processid;
   public int getProcessid() {
      return processid;
    }
   public void setProcessid(int processid) {
    this.processid = processid;
    }
   public void run(){
    int count=0;
    for(Thread t:Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()){
        ThreadEngine t1=(ThreadEngine)t;
         int processtid=t1.getProcessid();
        if(t.getState()==Thread.State.RUNNABLE)count++;
     }
    }

 }
```

Here i am trying to typecast the currently running threads into my custom thread class but i am getting cast exception.

I want to get processid's of currently running threads.How is it possible?

Comment: What makes you think that all `Thread`s in the JVM are instances of `ThreadEngine`? If you want to do this only for instances of `ThreadEngine`, use an `instanceof` check.

Comment: Naming: the word processId is usally used on the OS level for identifying a process. A process (launched through an executable) may spawn one or more threads which run in the same process. For identifying a thread in java there is the built in member name which you can pass as constructor argument.

Comment: @Andy Turner instanceof is working.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of easy ways to handle this.
[Full working code on online java ide](https://www.codiva.io/p/5fe35d12-8e8d-46f0-964f-f68bb3749d4d?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=threads1&utm_campaign=sof-answers)

What are you trying to achieve?
The run() method always runs in the thread were the instance is ThreadEngine.

So you could simply use `getProcessid()` in the run() method to access the process id.

At any other place, if you want to access the current thread, you could simply use
`Thread.currentThread()` that returns the current thread.

If you are looking for any thread instead of just current thread, then you should make sure if it is of the current instance type using the `instanceof` keyword.

I have attached the working code in [codiva java online compiler ide](https://www.codiva.io/p/5fe35d12-8e8d-46f0-964f-f68bb3749d4d?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=threads1&utm_campaign=sof-answers).

Comment: ya i have several threads in wait state and thread that is in running.For each thread a processid is created and i want to check all the processids which are in wait state and running.

Answer (score 1):

You are making the assumption that the only threads which exist in your JVM are the ones you have started. This isn't the case, as the following snippet illustrates when run on [<kbd>ideone</kbd>](http://ideone.com/SbBdfj):

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        for (Thread t : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) {
            System.out.println(t.getClass() + " " + t.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
class java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread Finalizer
class java.lang.Thread Signal Dispatcher
class java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler Reference Handler
class java.lang.Thread main
```

Despite the fact that the code creates no threads explicitly, there are 4 threads shown. So if your code *does* create threads, you should expect some extra threads in addition to yours.

As such, you need to check if the thread you are currently processing actually is an instance of the expected class before casting:

```
for(Thread t:Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()){
  if (t instanceof ThreadEngine) {
    ThreadEngine t1=(ThreadEngine)t;
    // ...
  }
}
```

This will simply ignore other types of thread.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is probably if the master thread which creates your ThreadEngine instances keeps a reference of each instance within a collection. Just iterate over this collection for calling getProcessid().

But: If you only want to count your running instances you do not need the processId, isn't it?